# Simple level system with xp, money, and levels

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple level system, but it somehow doesn't update the levels. Can anyone help me with this? (The money and xp works)

```
var money = 0;
var xp = 0;
var level = 1;

window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = 'Money: ' + money;
 document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = 'XP: ' + xp;
 document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = 'Current level: ' + level;
}

function giveExp(number){
 money = parseInt(money) + 50;
 xp = xp + 100;

 document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = 'Money: ' + money;
 document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = 'XP: ' + xp;
}


if (xp > 150 && xp < 450) {
 level = level + 1;
 document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = 'Current level: ' + level;
}
```

Comment: put the if into the gibeExp function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code + better strucuture and a working xp system:

```
var money=0,level=1,xp=0;

function updatecounters(){
    if (xp > 400) {
        level+=Math.floor(xp/400);// if xp is 1000, two levels up
        xp=xp%400;// what is left when increasing levels
     }
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = 'Money: ' + money;
    document.geElementById("xp").innerHTML = 'XP: ' + xp;
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = 'Current level: ' + level;
  }


 function giveExp(number){
     money +=  50;
     xp +=  100;
     updatecounters();//update
 }

   window.onload=updatecounters;//onload init counters
```

The better way (using an IIFE and Closure):

```
var user=(function(){
    window.onload=user.update;
    var money=0,level=1,xp=0;// no way to change these without updating (better work flow)
    return {
       increaseXP:function(val){
          xp+=val;
          if(xp>400){//enough xp for level up
           level+=Math.floor(xp/400);
           xp=xp%400;
         }
         user.update();
       },
     increaseMoney:function(val){
        money +=val;
        user.update();
     },
     update:function(){
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = 'Money: ' + money;
       document.geElementById("xp").innerHTML = 'XP: ' + xp;
       document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = 'Current level: ' + level;
    }};
    })();
```

use like this:

```
user.increaseXP(200);
user.increaseMoney(-500);// bad day :/
user.money=500; // error, so you cant change without updating -> prevent bugs
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `if` statement into the `giveExp` function:

```
function giveExp(number){
 money = parseInt(money) + 50;
 xp = xp + 100;

 document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = 'Money: ' + money;
 document.getElementById("xp").innerHTML = 'XP: ' + xp;

 if (xp > 150 && xp < 450) {
  level = level + 1;
  document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = 'Current level: ' + level;
 }

}
```

Comment: Ok it works, but is there a better way to create some kind of level system when you reach a amount of xp, you level up? Because when I click the button, I level up 2 times.

Comment: @Raul : what about resetting xp on level up (see my solution)...